# Should my questions 'substantive' be bisected or merged?

Tags: discussion

I posted my [questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/32125/8712) separately because in the earlier one, I couldn't determine which definition applied. Yet in the one now marked as a duplicate, all of the definitions seem to apply, but this is wrong.

As I tried to explain in my first paragraph, I'm contending against two different problems here with the same word. So would someone please advise if I may be allowed two separate questions? I fear that a merger would effect one lengthy, weary question asking about two *disparate* problems.

Answer (score 1):

Both questions are *already* "lengthy, weary". And it's worth noting that after three days, neither has yet attracted a single upvote or answer - all we have so far is three upvotes for my initial comment:-

> *Anything deeper than [dictionary definitions] is more a matter of fine points of **philosophy / morality / sociology** than [English language for learners as addressed by ELL].*

Both questions are entirely concerned with the *meaning* (in context) of ***substantive***. But even native speakers who are reasonably familiar with the word would find it almost impossible to give a clear-cut answer to either of the specific finely-nuanced questions raised (that's why non-one actually *has*).

---

Speaking for myself, I'm far from convinced questions asking about "word meaning" at this level are appropriate for ELL. There's a limit to the precision of any word in English (or indeed in *any* language), and beyond a certain point any discussion of the exact meaning of a usage in context becomes either wholly subjective ***or*** simply a discussion of the concepts raised by any given instance of usage (which could just as well be carried out in a different language; the specific words used aren't important).